# Cant resize the ImageView to smaller size

Tags: android, imageview

I am creating an application where when a service is started it will open a chat head like view overlay(Image). But I was able to achieve this while the image is very large and I could not change the size:

onCreate in service:

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        prefs = new PreferenceHelper(getApplicationContext());
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        Log.i(LOGSERVICE, "onCreate");
        chatHead = new ImageView(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floaticon);
        int width = 20; // ((display.getWidth()*20)/100)
        int height = 20;// ((display.getHeight()*30)/100)
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        chatHead.setLayoutParams(parms);

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        //Specify the view position
        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 20;

        //Add the view to the window
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mWindowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                        //remember the initial position.
                        initialX = params.x;
                        initialY = params.y;


                        //get the touch location
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        //Calculate the X and Y coordinates of the view.
                        params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);


                        //Update the layout with new X & Y coordinate
                        mWindowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your code from:

LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
        chatHead.setLayoutParams(parms);

to

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = chatHead.getLayoutParams();
params.width = 20;
params.height = 20;
```

chatHead.setLayoutParams(parms);